# Deleted Windows E:\ drive ; now how do I give that partition to Ubuntu?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows-7

I have installed Ubuntu 13.10 alongside Windows 7.
I've deleted one of my Windows drive (E:) through the app Disks in Ubuntu, but when I do 'create a new partition' with type chosen as ext4, a prompt appears:

> Error creating partition on /dev/sda:Command-line `parted-align optimal-script "/dev/sda"mkpart logical ext2 384777Mib 479045091327b"exited with non zero exit status 1:Error:You requested a prtition from 403GB to 479GB.The closest location we can manage is 403GB to 479GB.(udisk-error-quark,0).

What is this all about? Is there any way of adding any Windows partition to Ubuntu after installing it to the system?

I've also tried doing it by deleting it first from Windows and then trying to use that free space to make a ext4 partition in Ubuntu, but the same problem appears!

Comment: Take and upload the screenshot of your gparted partition editor to imgur.com.Finally post the uploaded link here.

Comment: I'm asking gparted screenshot.Search for gparted in dash.If it is not installed on your pc, then install it by running `sudo apt-get install gparted` command on terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've probably run into a rounding error -- the partitioning tool tried to align a partition to a 1MiB boundary and that ended up causing it to overlap with a preceding or following partition. The simplest way around this problem is to leave a small gap (~1MiB) before and/or after the partition you're creating.

Comment: Yups..It got solved by leaving a bit gap..Thanku :)

Answer (score 0):

do not use disks to manage partitions. rather use gparted. install gparted from software center and use that to make your partitions. it will not generate errors. you can create an ext4 as well as an ntfs partition. ext4 is only accessible in ubuntu whereas ntfs will be accessible by both windows and ubuntu.